# Pinescript: Paint the price of crossover candle

Tags: pine-script

I plan to take a long entry for a Crossover and wanted to find out

1. how to paint the closing price of the crossover on the chart?
2. Find out what would be the highest price of the last 10 candles when the crossover occurs?

Below function gives me the entry.

```
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input(title="Offset", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out1 = ema(src, len1)
out2 = ema(src, len2)
out3 = ema(src, len3)
Long_TP1 = crossover(out1,out3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study(title="Help (Price Cross)", overlay=true)
len1 = input(defval=5,    title="Length 1")
len2 = input(defval=13,   title="Length 2")
len3 = input(defval=19,   title="Length 3")
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input(title="Offset", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)

out1 = ema(src, len1)
out2 = ema(src, len2)
out3 = ema(src, len3)
Long_TP1 = crossover(out1, out3)

var price_cr =0.0
var high10 = 0.0
hitemp = highest(high, 10)

if Long_TP1
    price_cr := close
    high10 := hitemp

plot(price_cr, color=color.blue)  
plot(high10, color=color.red)
```

Comment: This plots the line on the chart. What I am looking for is the label at the particular candle only where the Cross occurred.

Comment: If you make corrections on the screenshot will be clearer.